# Creating new pandas columns with original value plus random number in error range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column 'INTENSITY' and a numpy array of same length containing the error for each intensity. I would like to generate columns with randomly generated numbers in the error range.

So far I use two nested for loops to create the new columns but I feel like this is inefficient:

```
theor_err = [ sqrt(abs(x)) for x in theor_df[str(INTENSITY)] ]
theor_err = np.asarray(theor_err)

for nr_sample in range(2):
    sample = np.zeros(len(theor_df[str(INTENSITY)]))
    for i, error in enumerate(theor_err):
        sample[i] = theor_df[str(INTENSITY)][i] + random.uniform(-error, error)
        theor_df['gen_{}'.format(nr_sample)] = Series(sample, index=theor_df.index)
theor_df.head()
```

Is there a more efficient way of approaching a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can handle arrays for you.  So, you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a=pd.DataFrame([10,20,15,30],columns=['INTENSITY'])
a['theor_err']=np.sqrt(np.abs(a.INTENSITY))
a['sample']=np.random.uniform(-a['theor_err'],a['theor_err'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to generate 6 samples. You can try to code below. You can tune the number of samples you want by setting the value `k`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[-5]], columns=["intensity"])
k = 6
sample_names = ["sample" + str(i+1) for i in range(k)]
df["err"] = np.sqrt(np.abs((df["intensity"])))
df[sample_names] = pd.DataFrame(
              df["err"].map(lambda x: np.random.uniform(-x, x, k)).values.tolist())
df.loc[:,sample_names] = df.loc[:,sample_names].add(df.intensity, axis=0)
```

[image]